# react native QR code no useful information

Tags: windows-10

As titled. I used some simple starter code and used npm start, it returned a QR CODE and some errors. I proceeded to scan the code with my iOS device, which says no useful information found. Anyway here's my screenshot of the error returned. It says there are two package-lock , which one should I keep?

[image: Screenshot of my error]

Comment: “It says there are two package-lock”—No, it does not. Please read the error message carefully. Did you perhaps name your project `react-native`? Also, what exactly did you do? What OS are you on? What tools are you using?

Comment: If you do have a text based error message just copy it. It's unnecessarily hard to read in your screenshot and won't allow people to copy and paste.

Comment: Recommend turning your title into a question to make it easier to tell what you need help with.

Comment: I am on the Windows 10 Operating System, and named my project AwesomeProject. It's my first time approaching ReactNative so I did not do anything other than simply doing the command "init AwesomeProject" and "npm start"

Comment: And yet there is another `package.json` in `E:\react-native`, as indicated by the error message. Surely you were following some guide or tutorial...?

Comment: I moved the file out of the react-native folder and this problem no longer exists. Thanks!